# Chrome Extension Browser Action not Appearing

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make an extension for Google Chrome, and in the early stages of coding it, the icon for the browser action would appear, but now that I've added an action to it, it won't show up. The manifest.json is here:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Test",
    "description": "Test extension"
    "version": "0.1",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `,` after the `description` entity, and put a `}` at wrong place.

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Test",
    "description": "Test extension",
    "version": "0.1",
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    }
}
```

Comment: That didn't seem to fix the issue, there's a comma now, and I've refreshed the extension, but it's still not showing up in the top right.

Comment: @BladeOfDismay, I have updated the code. You just also put a `}` at the wrong place.